# maximum sum of subarray (Python)

Tags: python, input

the function finds the maximum sum of subarray

```
def kad(l):
max_c=max_g=0
for i in range(0,len(l)):
    max_c=max(l[i],l[i]+max_c)

    if(max_c>max_g):

        max_g=max_c
return max_g        
print(max_c)
```

The problem is in taking the input as the function  ***kad(l)*** is not executing, which I expect to be executed for each list created.

```
# to take input

t=int(input("test case")) ## TEST CASES
for k in range (0,t):
   n=int(input(" num"))    # TOTAL NUMBERS IN EACH TEST CASE
   l=[int(input()) for i in range(0,n)]
   if(len(l)>0):
    kad(l)

    print(l)
```

Comment: First fix your indentation, once that is done I think it executes, but you expected it to print, which it doesnt since your print is after your return. You also just throw away the returned result.

Comment: You have some indentation errors, the code shouldn't run at all

Comment: thanks @OlivierMelançon **your print is after your return** this is the catch you got it right thanks a lot